# Obtain SellerSKU from ASIN number

Tags: amazon-product-api

I need to get the SellerSKU value for an item located on an Amazon storefront based on the Amazon ASIN value.  I've tried many of the methods in the MarketplaceWebServiceProducts endpoint, but to no avail.

Any information is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to pull the data via any reports, or which API are you using? ( I am assuming products, but I am not sure of your use case)

Comment: Yes I am using the Products API.  The information needs to be taken 100% programmatically and at my will when I call for it.  All the methods available in the Products API has no problem sharing a wealth of information ie Product Dimensions and Weight, but I can't seem to find ANY kind of identifier (sku, upc, isbn) other than the ASIN number.  There is a field buried deep in the return object called SellerSkuIdentifier, but it always returns null, no matter what I try to do.

Comment: @JoshHines were you ever able to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are using the products API (you mention the products endpoint) the API reference states:

> GetMatchingProductForId
>
> The GetMatchingProductForId operation returns
> a list of products and their attributes, based on a list of product
> identifier values that you specify. Possible product identifiers are
> ASIN, SellerSKU, UPC, EAN, ISBN, and JAN.

So the API call to make is GetMatchingProductForId. See page 13 of the products API located [here](https://images-na.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/G/01/mwsportal/doc/en_US/products/MWSProductsApiReference._V401383218_.pdf)

Comment: This is to call based on certain identifiers, this call doesn't naturally return whatever identifiers I want.  IE: I specify SellerSKU. It will look for products based on SellerSKU, it won't return products with their SellerSKU information available in the return object.

Comment: Have you considered generating an inventory report and storing the sku and ASIN combo in either a dictionary, or alternatively into a database for retrieval and processing?

Comment: Yes I have, the problem is, is that my client could change these SKUs at any given time for any number of (valid) reasons.  So I need to retrieve the SKUs in real time unfortunately.

Comment: You may want to post on the MWS developer forums here: https://sellercentral.amazon.com/forums/forum.jspa?forumID=35&start=0 Some excellent folks answer questions on it along with some Amazon people - I'm not sure if there is an API to do exactly what you need and you may need to resort to the reports option and request reports as required - it will introduce a time delay of ~15 minutes depending on amount of sku's but it would work.  Aside from that, you may be forced to scrape the pages...

Comment: Yeah I'll definitely have to do that, thanks so much for your time and help Rob!